# Is there such a thing a underwater climbing plants?

Tags: aquarium, aquatic-plants

I'm looking for a plant which grows up the pipe of my undergravel filter (in a 30 l freshwater aquarium), i.e. from ground to the water surface growing precisely around the pipe.

I'm aware that I could use a plant which is so large that it would cover the tube, or that I could put a mat around the tube and let Java ferns grow on it. It's more of a knowledge question.

I'm aware of the fact that the plant would limit the maintainability of the filter installation.

In case you don't know yet, what an undergravel filter is: http://animals.howstuffworks.com/pets/choosing-aquarium-equipment7.htm

Answer (score 2):

A web search for "underwater climbing plant" yielded (removed due to link rot), which suggests Hydrocotyle Japan. You should be able to train it around the pipe as it sends out roots every few centimeters like ivy. It might be easier if you first wrap some sort of netting around the pipe, so that the roots have something to anchor on.

I myself don't know much about fish, so I can't guarantee that Hydrocotyle Japan is safe for your fish. However, that link is an aquarium site, so I suspect that if you research the plant, you'll find it's safe.

Comment: it is a fairly common aquarium plant https://tropica.com/en/plants/plantdetails/Hydrocotyletripartita(039B)/4458 i do not think any underwater plants have had the need to evolve the ability to climb as the only thing needed for this type of plants is a stem and leaves lighter than water to reach for the sun.